# Does Hazelcast support this 3 node network partition?

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast 3.11 and testing the following network situation.

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

Where A and B are connected in both directions, A and C are connected in both directions, and B and C are disconnected. Normally all the nodes are connected, so I programatically configure each IP for each node using the TcpIp config.

When I introduce the network failure, node B suspects node C because it has not sent any heartbeats, then immediately after it suspects node A for reason "explicit suspicion".

Node C suspects node B because it has not sent any heartbeats. It stays in the same cluster as node A.
Is the "explicit suspicion" Hazelcast's way of creating 2 completely connected partitions instead of 1 that is not completely connected? Is there way to configure Hazelcast to have this type of network failure and keep A connected to both A and C?

As a side note, I'm only interested in using the ReplicatedMap and distributed event APIs.

Edit: The following code is run once on each of the 3 servers which are named A, B, and C. They are running once instance of hazelcast each.

```
public HazelcastInstance getHazelcastInstance() {
    Config config = new Config();
    config
        .getGroupConfig( )
        .setName( localFacility.getName() )
        .setPassword( clusterPassword );

    NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();              

    //Disable multicast
    JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();
    joinConfig
        .getMulticastConfig()
        .setEnabled( false );

    // Interface config
    InterfacesConfig interfaceConfig = networkConfig.getInterfaces();
    IntraFacilityProperties intrafacilityProperties = facilityPropertiesUtil.getCurrentIntrafacilityProperties();
    String primaryHostname = intrafacilityProperties.getHostname();
    String secondaryHostname = intrafacilityProperties.getBackupHostname();

    try {

        InetAddress primaryIp = InetAddress.getByName( primaryHostname );
        InetAddress secondaryIp = InetAddress.getByName( secondaryHostname );

        // Specify which network interfaces to use based on the configured hostnames
        interfaceConfig
            .setEnabled( true )
            .addInterface( primaryIp.getHostAddress() )
            .addInterface( secondaryIp.getHostAddress() );

    } catch ( UnknownHostException e ) {

        if ( logger.isErrorEnabled() ) {
            logger.error( "Caught UnknownHostException", e );
        }

        throw new HazelcastInstantiationException( e.getMessage() );
    }


    //Enable the tcp ip config.
    TcpIpConfig ipConfig = joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig();
    ipConfig.setEnabled( true );

    try{ 
        // Loops through all servers regardless of which server this is.
        for( IntraFacilityProperties member : facilityPropertiesUtil.getIntraFacilityProperties() ) {
            ipConfig.addMember( InetAddress.getByName( member.getHostname() ).getHostAddress() );
            ipConfig.addMember( InetAddress.getByName( member.getBackupHostname() ).getHostAddress() );
        }
    } catch( UnknownHostException e ) {
        if ( logger.isErrorEnabled() ) {
            logger.error( "Caught UnknownHostException", e );
        }

        throw new HazelcastInstantiationException( e.getMessage() );
    }

    ReplicatedMapConfig repMapCfg = new ReplicatedMapConfig();
    repMapCfg.setName( "default" )
             .setMergePolicyConfig( new MergePolicyConfig()
             .setPolicy( "LatestAccessMergePolicy" ) );
    config.addReplicatedMapConfig( repMapCfg );

    config.setProperty( "hazelcast.heartbeat.failuredetector.type", "deadline" );
    config.setProperty( "hazelcast.heartbeat.interval.seconds", hzHeartbeatInterval );
    config.setProperty( "hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds", hzHeartbeatTimeout );
    config.setProperty( "hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds", hzMergeFirstDelay );
    config.setProperty( "hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds", hzMergeNextDelay );
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance( config );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble following your description here since your mixing network partition with node.  Either a node is a member of the cluster or it is not.  Are you asking specifically about network routing here?  Please provide some sample code and configuration.

Comment: I've added the code to show the tcpIp config, and I've edited the question since I think I might be misusing partition to mean the network failure that causes a partition. I hope this helps.
In the presence of this failure, I could see how it's possible to route information that needs to go from B<->C through A. Could that be done with hazelcast configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  If I'm understanding your description.  You have a cluster with nodes A, B, and C.  A network partitioned occurred between B & C.  Routes between A<-->B and A<-->C are still intact.  According to your description Node B sent an explicit suspicion event to Node A.  This is because Node A sent a heartbeat request to B but B already existed the cluster and thusly created its own single member cluster.  Node A and C remain in the cluster.  Hazelcast does not allow a node to be a member of more than one cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which node is master (the one came up first in the cluster). If A is the master then the cluster will continue to operate normally except the operations originating from C that are meant for node B will be Operation timed out, and vice-versa for B to C. If the cluster is used in client-server mode then there is no impact on data operations generating from the client except the backups i.e. if some data that is primarily stored in B but needs to be backed up on C, it will fail. So in case of a failure of either B or C, you will end up loosing data.

If B or C were the master then the cluster will split into B-A and C or C-A and B. In that case, standard split brain handling applies.